# styling the quicklaunch selected items in sharepoint 2007

Tags: 2007

Can anybody tell me how to style the selected state of a menu choice (wheather its a menu header or a menu item ) from the quicklaunch menu in a sharepoint 2007 site?

Regards
Dean

Comment: I think this is a master page change.  You would have to do it in SPD or you can take the master page into VS and deploy the changes through there.

Comment: Could you tell me where and what in the master page I would need to change?